# Proof that derived functors don't depend on choice of resolution.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Can somebody help me out with this? Let $X$ be an object in an abelian category $A$ with enough injectives, let $0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow M^{\bullet}$ be an injective resolution , let $0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow N^{\bullet}$ be another injective resolution , let $F:A \rightarrow B$ (where $B$ is an abelian category) be a left exact functor, how does one go about proving that both resolutions induce the same cohomology groups $R^iF(X)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof uses a lemma known as "The Fundamental Lemma of Homological Algebra" or "The Comparison Theorem for Resolutions."

> **Lemma.** Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category with enough injectives, $X \longrightarrow I^\bullet$ an injective resolution of $X \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{A})$, and $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(Y, X)$. Then for every resolution $Y \longrightarrow J^\bullet$, there is a cochain map $\tilde{f}: J^\bullet \longrightarrow I^\bullet$ lifting $f$. Furthermore, $\tilde{f}$ is unique up to chain homotopy equivalence.

It follows that if $X \longrightarrow I^\bullet$ and $X \longrightarrow J^\bullet$ are two injective resoutions of the same object, $I^\bullet$ and $J^\bullet$ are chain homotopy equivalent. Hence the cohomologies $H^i(F(I^\bullet))$ and $H^i(F(J^\bullet))$ are canonically isomorphic.

The proof of the fundamental lemma is slightly lengthy (but not too difficult). See Theorem 2.2.6 of Weibel's *An Introduction to Homological Algebra* or Theorem 2.22 of Davis and Kirk's *Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology* for a proof.